# Rails javascript doesn't work in production mode

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets, dev-to-production

I got an object which shows icons selection toolbar like in skype. Icon images are shown correctly, but when I click on an icon in production mode, the selected icon doesn't appear in text.

I put the icon image html to console and found out that it is right the same that selected image in toolbar consists of. I'm confused a lot. What is wrong?

**app/assets/javascripts/emoticons.js**

```
function EmoticonsToolbar(jquery_element){
  var e = jquery_element;
  var top  = e.offset().top;  // store toolbar button initial position
  var left = e.offset().left;
  var onIconClick_callback;   // method to insert icon image html in text

  this.hide = function(){
    e.hide();
  };

  // icon click event handler
  this.onIconClick = function(eventObject){
    e.hide();
    var html = $(eventObject.target).parent().html().replace(/\n\s+|\s+\n/g, '');




    console.log(html);
    // html here: '<img title="ru.emoticons. " src="/assets/emoticons/24x24/02-72977ee3c26c7946176e85da16a13c98.png">'
    // that url returnes the image if being typed in address bar




    onIconClick_callback(html);
    eventObject.stopPropagation();
    };

  // show icon selection toolbar above the editor button
  this.attach_to = function(element, callback){
    onIconClick_callback = callback;
    var newTop  = element.offset().top  - top  - 10 - e.height();
    var newLeft = element.offset().left - left + 10;
    e.css({top:newTop, left:newLeft, visibility:'visible'}).show();
    };
};
```

And here is an editor panel button "Insert emoticon", which shows emoticon toolbar, and handles the html of selected icon image.

**app/assets/javascripts/control/user/sites/pages.js**

```
function nicEditorEmoticonButton(){   
  var self;
  this.init = function(){
    self = this;
  };

  // Search text input and set focus on it
  var setFocusBackToText = function(){
    $(self.elm).closest('div.widget').find('div.nicEdit-main').focus();
  };

  this.mouseClick = function(eventObject) {
    var paste_icon_html = function(html){
      // create a DOM node from the given html
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = html;
      var node = div.childNodes[0];

      // get selection if any, insert html as a Node
      var range = se.getRng();
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(node);
      range.setEndAfter(node);
      range.setStartAfter(node);
      setFocusBackToText();
    };

    // get nicEdit selected instance - se
    var se = this.ne.selectedInstance;
    if(se){
      emoticonsToolbar.attach_to($(this.button), paste_icon_html);
    } else {
      // no editor selected, so let select this one
      setFocusBackToText();
    }
  };
};


var emoticonButtonOptions = {
  buttons : {
    'emoticonToolbar' : {name : __('Emoticon menu bar button'), type : 'nicEditorEmoticonButton'}
  }, iconFiles : {'emoticonToolbar' : '/assets/emoticons/ab.gif'}
};
```

I did run `rake assets:precompile`

**UPDATE 1**: added aplication.js fragment

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./control
//= require_tree ./popup
//= require_tree ./global
//= require_tree ./lib
//= require hide_on_body_click.js
//= require popup_messages.js
//= require root.js
//= require diaries.js
//= require emoticons.js

//... and plenty of code below
```

**UPDATE 2**: A'm sure the problem is in `range.insertNode(node)`, because `range.deleteContent()` deletes selection indeed, and `setFocusBackToText()` also does its job.

**app/assets/javascripts/emoticons.js**

```
  // get selection if any, insert html as a Node
  var range = se.getRng();
  range.deleteContents();
  range.insertNode(node); // <- doesn't work in production environment
  range.setEndAfter(node);
  range.setStartAfter(node);
  setFocusBackToText();
```

Comment: Can you post your `application.js` file ?

Comment: What is the location to your `control` or `popup` or `global` directory? Do you mean to include all the `lib` directory (it contains  `assets/stylesheets` also) ?

Comment: `./lib` means `*.js` files under `app/assets/javascripts/lib`, and  `control`, `popup`, `global` all reside in `app/assets/javascripts`

Comment: The last detail: what is the name of file with the brocken functionality?

Comment: it's name is `app/assets/javascripts/control/user/sites/pages.js`

Comment: Sorry, went to clean my yard of snow.

Answer (score 0):

I your case I would suggest to use `index.js` file . It is described in details in this [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) (look for 2.1.2).

In your directory `app/assets/javascripts/control/` you should create a new manifest file named `index.js` with (simplified) content :

```
//= require_tree .
```

Then in your `application.js` :

```
//= require control
```

(notice the name of directory with index.js file should match the required lib in `application.js`).

This way you can nest your assets libraries and decrease the lines in the main manifest file.

Comment: Hm, ok, but how does that relate to the fact, that all the emoticons.js script lines, but one perform. See UPDATE 2